# UIScrollView start scrolling threshold

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uikit

I'm looking for a way of 'sticking' a UIScrollView to it's position unless the touch has been moved by a certain threshold, at which point it will jump to where it should have scrolled to and continue scrolling.

The reason for this is that I have a vertical scroll and each cell inside the UIScrollView has a horizontal scroll. So I'd like to introduce a slight 'stickyness' to make sure the user doesn't accidentally scroll vertically when they mean to scroll horizontally.

I started by hijacking the `contentOffset` property in `scrollViewDidScroll`. The trouble with that is I cannot find out how much the scrollView would have moved by if I were setting the `contentOffset`

If I try to add a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to the class then it overrides the `UIScrollView` and the `UIScrollView` becomes unresponsive.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

EDIT: edits based on comments.

Comment: Seems like that could create a confusing user experience. Can you add more detail to your question to explain exactly why you want to do that? What's in your scroll view? Should the scroll "jump" to where the user has dragged? Or, after dragging the "threshold" distance, act like the user has just *started* dragging?

Comment: @DonMag I've updated my question but it's basically because I have horizontal scrollviews within each cell of the vertical scrollview.

Comment: So... vertical scroll view with two horizontal scroll views... If I start dragging left in a horizontal scroll view, and up slightly, you don't want vertical scrolling. What happens if your "vertical threshold" is, say, 50-pts, and I drag left 200-pts and *then* drag up 51-pts? Horizontal scroll view continues scrolling, and vertical scroll view starts scrolling (jumping up 50-pts)?